# multiple beanstalkd clients to process one job

Tags: beanstalkd

Is there a possibility in beanstalkd to process one job by multiply clients? 
How job should be deleted in this case?

I would like to send message from one server to 10 another servers, so job will be completed on all of them - it is about update local data on servers.

Should i choose any another MQ system for this kind of task?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have one job being run on all ten other servers, and have them all acknowledge it as complete.

You could use that first message to then create one message per server, probably in separate tubes (for example, named *worker01* .. *worker10*). With a tube per server, you'd also have an advantage of quickly and easily seeing how many jobs are in each tube - so you can see if any servers aren't picking up messages.